# Monitoring system in microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

Do all microcontrollers you have encountered have a monitoring program inside it? For example, the HC11 has the Buffalo monitoring system that you can use to interact with the MCU in a finished product, that is, a PC computer can interact with the circuit module via Buffalo. Is this commonly done?

I'm only familiar with the HC11. Do other microcontrollers have it too? What is the proper term for the monitoring and interfacing subsystem within it?

Comment: Can you provide some links for this "Buffalo"? Those of us who haven't used the HC11 don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: From what I can recalll, the Buffalo monitor program was optional. The answer is no - not all microcontrollers have a monitor program at it was uncommon. Nowadays most of the microcontrollers have inbuilt debug hardware that allow you to do more than what Buffalo did.

Comment: The link is in someone answer below. You used Buffalo to load the microcontroller program into its eeprom. You can also edit its memory and run subroutine inside it. You used a terminal to access Buffalo. How about in other microcontroller, how do you test the program in it, unless you need to burn the eprom dozens of time daily to test the program?

Comment: Monitor subsystem is no more needed and is simplified to the "strict" minimum. You need now only a program "loader". All other tasks can be done with "simulators". I wrote a simulator (execution line by line displaying all registers content) for the 8080, 6800 and 6502 ... Not very difficult, just a little "bit" long ... http://www.hc11.demon.nl/thrsim11/thrsim11.htm

Comment: If you don't have Buffalo ... https://github.com/tonypdmtr/buffalo

Comment: I used Buffalo in the HC11 since im familiarizing with machine language. I always thought it was like Jarvis or Just A Rather Very Intelligent System (J.A.R.V.I.S.) . So its not necessary in modern day microcontroller but then is it not harder to interact with machine language in the MCU without it..

Comment: @Jtl, What are you really asking? If you're asking how to get started with a modern microcontroller, then buy an eval board like this: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nxp-usa-inc/FRDM-KE06Z/4765764 You'll need; the eval board (less than $50 U.S.), a USB cable, a Windows PC, and software and documentation that you download for free from the manufacturer's web site. (Maybe also an external power supply, I forget whether the board can run from USB power alone...) You probably won't be writing any assembly code though. You can, but there's no need for it.

Comment: P.S., One nice thing about the Kinetis FRDM eval boards: The I/O connectors are designed to be compatible with Arduino "shields." Bad part though is, there are no I/O connectors. You have to buy those separately, and solder them on to the board yourself.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned thrsim11 because I just tried it today and found an error I missed the whole week which got me analyzing for hours each day. It so happened I used double labels "Loop" in the assemble language, which messed everything up.  Do all microcontrollers have their version of thrsim11?  I only know assembly language. What c language is compatible with the Hc11? any links? Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "monitor," not "monitoring system." I don't know where the name "monitor" came from, but a monitor is a primitive program loader—a sort of rudimentary operating system that may or may not provide any services to the programs that it loads and starts.

No. Not all microcontrollers contain built-in monitors. In fact, most of the ones that I have ever worked with do not. [BUFFALO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68HC11#Implementations), for that matter, is not built-in to every 68HC11 microprocessor, but rather, it *can* be built-in to [evaluation boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor_development_board) or other systems that are based on the 68HC11.

Many modern microcontrollers boot from, and execute code exclusively from on-board, programmable read-only memory. A hardware "device programmer" (e.g., [like this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/silicon-labs/UDA-32-KIT/3523712)) is used in conjunction with development tools running on a standard PC to "burn" the program into the chip without any need for a software "monitor."

Comment: for example you want the pc program to run different subroutine for example to display E1 and E2 data input for channel 1 and channel 2. Without any loader in the microcontroller..how do you run channel 1 or channel 2 subroutine? unless the program in your microcontroller can make you enter different inputs for channel 1 or channel 2 choices?

Comment: @Jtl, As a really simplistic example, If I wanted a microcontroller program to do either one of two things, I could have it sense a GPIO input when it booted up, and behave one way if the input were high, or the other way if the input were low. A toggle switch connected to the input could set it one way or the other. OTOH, I have programmed microcontrollers in devices that had keypads and LCD screens for user interaction... It depends on the scope of the project.

Comment: Hi consider the buffalo running in the HC11, what commands do you use to still access the HC11 (after already running)  and change register A while looping so it can branch to an address that executes SEI or Set Interrupt Mask which basically turns off say the timer interrupt?

Comment: @Jtl, That's a new question. You should post it as a new [_Question_](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on the site so that everybody can see it instead of just asking me in a comment here. I have not used BUFFALO, so I won't be able to help you with it. But, if you post it as a new _Question,_ then somebody else might read it and help you.